# can't receive messages on device using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i've followed google instruction on initiating a gcm server and client. 
my problem is though i get a successful gcm from server :

> MulticastResult(multicast_id=8287827393174436535,total=1,success=1,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results:
>   [[ messageId=0:1366468335181772%8e1522ac00000031 ]]

i'm not able to see any movement of receiving a message on the client - onMessage() isn't called. 
client id as well as server id are correct as far as i can tell.

i'd appreciate any help... :)

**the server side code :**

```
try {

Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);
Message message = new Message.Builder().collapseKey("1")
        .timeToLive(3)
        .delayWhileIdle(true)
        .addData("message",
                "this text will be seen in notification bar!!").build();

ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();

devices.add(DEVICE_ID1); 
//devices.add(DEVICE_ID2);

MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devices, 2);
//Result result = sender.send(message, DEVICE_ID1, 2);
System.out.println(result.toString());
if (result.getResults() != null) {
    int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
    if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
    }
} else {
    int error = result.getFailure();
    System.out.println(error);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

**the client code :** 
**registering :**

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
          GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); // Note: get the sender id from configuration.
          String regIdString = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
          Log.v(TAG, "RegisterId, regId: " + regIdString);
        } else {

          Log.v(TAG, "Already registered, regId: " + regId);
        }
```

**and gcmIntentServiceCreated (partly) :**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
public GCMIntentService(){
        super(SENDER_ID);       
    }
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.i("Registration", "Got a message!");
             Log.i("Registration", context.toString() + " " + intent.toString());
    }
...
}
```

**client's manifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"></permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" 
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

To maximise your chances of receiving the message, I would not set the time_to_live at a mere 3 seconds. I'd omit this parameter altogether so that it takes the default value of 4 weeks. I would also set delay_while to false, so that the phone gets the message even whilst idle.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help. server sent its message but even though the emulator is open at the client app, it doesn't look like the message was received since it's not on the logcat.

Comment: Pity, don't know what to suggest other than to check with the debugger that the registration ID is correct (with a breakpoint in the 'already registered' bit)

Answer (score 0):

Well your message is surely getting sent to your device since gcm sends a success status of 1. Try to check the GCMReceiver code of your app.

Comment: thanks, there isn's a GCMReceiver code, as far as i can understand, my class extending GCMBaseIntentService should do the recieving?

Comment: yep. that is what i meant. check for correctness of the receiver. because it seems gcm sender is sending. so check wat went wrong after that

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code in your onMessage method:

```
Log.i("Registration", "Got a message!");
             Log.i("Registration", context.toString() + " " + intent.toString());
```

to this:

```
String message=intent.getStringExtra("message"); 
Log.w("The message received is", message);
```

hope this help