# google cloud message 3.0 device not receive message

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I followed "quickstart sample" and the instructions of google cloud message latest version in link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client , and download project from this instructions . I succeed get device's token , and I have a php server to send to google cloud , but I can not get message from my device . Can you please here help me.

I download project from this site which is recommend in this link above

$ git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git

Below is my server code

**gcm.php**

```
 // Payload data you want to send to Android device(s)
        // (it will be accessible via intent extras)    
        $data = array('message' => 'Hello World!');

        // The recipient registration tokens for this notification
        // https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/  

        $ids = array('foD2qlwvb9U:APA91bGOD6VD8GxGtZXmg-oFwDElMCXNOxptLXvNL3NHzKenwUYKzUFUbIapBhuuOW2ee8oC3ZUPdGRcjmOrA5B4zrzG_UQtj7soqjisM4NUHe4L4IfSjoWRiXKJfQ_918XDgX11hWdT');

        // Send push notification via Google Cloud Messaging
        sendPushNotification($data, $ids);

        function sendPushNotification($data, $ids)
        {
            // Insert real GCM API key from the Google APIs Console
            // https://code.google.com/apis/console/            

            // Set POST request body
            $post = array(
                            'registration_ids'  => $ids,
                            'data'              => $data,
                         );

            // Set CURL request headers 
            $headers = array( 
                                'Authorization: key=AIzaSyCGw1NOaemsZWUFbUWcLCPP5p_Kcvmc9mg',
                                'Content-Type: application/json'
                            );

            // Initialize curl handle       
            $ch = curl_init();

            // Set URL to GCM push endpoint     
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');

            // Set request method to POST       
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

            // Set custom request headers       
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

            // Get the response back as string instead of printing it       
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Set JSON post data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));

            // Actually send the request    
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            // Handle errors
            if (curl_errno($ch))
            {
                echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error($ch);
            }

            // Close curl handle
            curl_close($ch);

            // Debug GCM response       
            echo $result;


        }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <permission android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
        <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyGcmListenerService.java**

```
package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I got the message from server :

> {"multicast_id":5585998123799628757,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1464946787970982%744ab298f9fd7ecd"}]}

I googled many tutorial, blog but my device still can not get message . Do I miss something ? My internet is good because I can open webpage.

**SOLVED** : I change to firebase cloud message and it work.
Thanks for all friends here help me.

Comment: Since you got a success response it is likely that the issue is on the client (Android) side. Could you add your implementation of MyGcmListenerService to your question?

Comment: The backend code seems to be fine. If I'm right, you're using a template. I second Arthur on this one. It might be with your GCMListenerService

Comment: Dear @Arthur Thompson I edited my post adding MyGcmListenerService.java code . Thanks for your reply

Comment: Dear @McAwesomville I edited my post adding MyGcmListenerService.java code . Thanks for your reply

Comment: You mentioned that this is just the sample client code for Android, did you change anything or is this just what it was when downloaded?

Comment: Dear @intj j , I did not change anything

Comment: I just download sample client code and then install to my device when I'm at office and no message , but when I come back home my device get message . It's look like problem comes from network setup , or delay from GCM , is it ?

Comment: Does onMessageReceived ever get called? Do you see the log messages for the "from" and the "message" in the logcat?

Comment: No it doesn't . I added log right below onMessageReceived but it did not call

Answer (score 0):

Try the following workarounds:

- Make sure you've set your SENDER ID you've received from Google correctly.
- Make sure your device was registered with Google's GCM service correctly.
- Make sure you are sending the push to the correct reg id you've received from Google. and that you didn't receive an error from Google GCM service.
- Change it to delay_while_idle = 0 if you want your wakelock permission to make any difference. If it was set to [`delay_while_idle = 1`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), the message won't reach the device if it's idle.
- Some times it takes time for the push to arrive (but never too much time, then there is a problem). Check what's the "time to live" of the push you've sent.

You can also check these related questions:

- [Why I can't receive messages from GCM on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884338/why-i-cant-receive-messages-from-gcm-on-android-device)
- [Can't receive messages using Google Cloud Messaging for Android (not the helper library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397056/cant-receive-messages-using-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-not-the-helper)
- [can't receive messages on device using GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121573/cant-receive-messages-on-device-using-gcm)

  > To maximise your chances of receiving the message, I would not set the time_to_live at a mere 3 seconds. I'd omit this parameter altogether so that it takes the default value of 4 weeks. I would also set delay_while to false, so that the phone gets the message even whilst idle.

Comment: Dear @abielita, is "SENDER ID" a server key in "Credentials" ? My device registered with GCM because I can get the token key response from GCM by using logcat . I test from my device NovaP in company , but when I go to another place with another network setup my device can get message from GCM which was be send before . I think maybe problem comes from network setup.

Comment: And I heard that we need to allow port 5228 . Is it right ? If this is right , what can I do to allow port 5228 . And what happen if another network setup don't allow port 5228 ? How can we use GCM everywhere ?